# Wrap text with label

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to get jQuery to set a label on the "untagged" element before a text input.  However, it seems to be setting the label on the previous tag.  I can't manually set a label in the code as it is auto-generated and the plugin developer has removed labels on form fields.  Here is the code for one of the fields I have at the moment:

```
<div id="_dgx_donate_donor_first_name" class="text-input-section">
  <div id="_dgx_donate_donor_first_name-error-message" style="display:none" class="seamless-donations-error-message-field"></div>
  First Name:
  <input type="text" name="_dgx_donate_donor_first_name" value="" size="20" data-validate="required" id="text_dgx_donate_donor_first_name" class="text-box">
</div>
```

When I select the first item inside the div, it wraps the label around the `_dgx_donate_donor_first_name-error-message` div.  If I say to choose the second element, it picks the `input` field.  I want to use the text in the middle.  My jQuery currently is:

```
$('#dgx-donate-container .text-input-section').each(function(){
  var c = 'text'+$(this).find('input[type="text"]').attr('name');
  $(this).find('input[type="text"]').attr('id', c).addClass('text-box');
  $(this).find(':first-child:not(#donation_header)').next().wrap('<label for="'+c+'" />');
});
```

Not pretty, but so far it seems to work.  (I think I will also need to change the ID, but since I am only using the label for styling purposes, I think I should be ok for now.)

Any suggestions on how I would select the text?  The format for each of the fields is exactly the same as this one.

Comment: Do you want the text in the input box or the text where 'First Name:' is?

Comment: I want `First Name:` to become `<label for="labelname">First Name:</label>`, but it currently either wraps the label around the `<div>` or the `<input>`.

Comment: is it always in the text input section class? if so $(".text-input-section") .contents() .filter(function () { return this.nodeType === 3; }) .wrap("<label></label>");

Comment: Yes.  The only things that change are the field specific IDs and the text.  The classes (`text-input-section` and `text-box`) are classes that I've added.

Comment: Thanks! Can you post your suggestion as an answer? Mostly because I used your solution and it worked and I want to give you credit for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(function(){
    var div = $("#_dgx_donate_donor_first_name");
    var txt = $.trim(div.text());
    var txtNodes = div.contents().filter(function(){
        return this.nodeType === 3;
    }).remove();
    //console.log(txtNodes);
    //div.text("");    //don't do this, it will empty your div
    var input = div.find("input");
    var name = input.attr("name");
    var lbl = $("<label for='" + name + "'>" + txt + "</label>");
    lbl.insertBefore(input);

});
```

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/kaheidt/hbfuLj1b/)

Answer (score 1):

Use [`wrapInner`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapInner/1/), then re-add the other nodes:

```
$('#dgx-donate-container .text-input-section').each(function(){
    var c = 'text'+$(this).find('input[type="text"]').attr('name');
    $(this).find('input[type="text"]').attr('id', c).addClass('text-box');
    firstDiv = $(this).children('div:first');
    input = $(this).children('input');
    $(this).wrapInner('<label for="'+c+'" />')
    .prepend(firstDiv)
    .append(input);
});
```

[**Example Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/b4y7vwp4/16/)